# viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear is not called on "presenting controller" when present controller using UIPresentationController

Tags: objective-c, swift, uikit, uipresentingcontroller

I can’t find a conclusive answer when presenting using `UIPresentationController` that declares `presentationStyle` to be `.FullScreen` or `.OverFullScreen`, `view(Will|Did)Disappear` is not called on presenting controller.

I saw some suggestions to call `beginAppearanceTransition` and alike manually - but that seems like an unrelated API for container controllers. Does anyone know how to implement it properly?

`view(Will|Did)Appear` is called normally on presented controller, but that seems to be a sideeffect of adding a view of a view controller to a hierarchy

Not too much documentation on `UIPresentationController.presentationStyle`, which I expected to affect UIKit’s behavior when it comes to messaging presenting view controller, not only “appearance of the presented content”.

Comment: The documentation for `viewWillDisappear` states: *Notifies the view controller that its view is about to be removed from a view hierarchy.*  When you present modally, the previous view isn't removed from the hierarchy, so that method won't be invoked.

Comment: true, but it's being called every time you use `presentViewController:animated:`, right? That's the behavior I'd expect UIKit replaces if my custom `UIPresentationController` claims to be a full screen one